# google finance function in google sheets to get all time high price?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-finance

Is it possible to get the all time high for a ticker using google finance function in google sheets? Can't find it in https://blog.sheetgo.com/google-sheets-formulas/googlefinance-formula-google-sheets/, but I do see 52 week high

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like that.

```
=MAX(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "high", DATE(2010,1,2), TODAY(), "DAILY"),,2))
```

- In this example I am getting the highest price since 2020 until today;
- Be aware, if you use this function with a high ticker number, you may have a performance issue.

Comment: what do you mean by high ticker number?

Comment: @user3226932, the symbol "GOOG", "AAPL", "TSLA".

Comment: @player0, I don't know how he's using it. But if he needs to look up the price of 10,000 companies and there are probably other functions, graphics... the information may take a few seconds to load. Before doing it is difficult to say if he will have this problem.